# How could I synchronize multiple threads with only the use of pthread mutexes?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, mutex

I was trying to make three threads that each open a different input file, read a single character from it and set it to a global variable and then wait for the next thread to read a single character from the file it opens and also set it to that global variable then move onto the next thread.

In the main, I opened a `file.out` to write the characters to. So the main would just read from the global variable and write to the `.out` file in the order of the character read by thread1, thread2, thread3, thread1, thread2, 3..etc.

this is what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>


//global char variables
char globalVAR1;
char globalVAR2;
char globalVAR3;

//define mutexes
pthread_mutex_t mutexOne;
pthread_mutex_t mutexTwo;
pthread_mutex_t mutexThree;


void *threadOne(void *arg){
    FILE *fileOne;
    fileOne = fopen("hw5-1.in", "r");

    char mChr1;

    //read each char
    if(fileOne == NULL){
        perror("file one error\n");
    }

    while(!feof(fileOne)){
        fscanf(fileOne, "%c\n", &mChr1);
        printf("char read: %c \n", mChr1);

        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexOne);
        globalVAR1 = mChr1;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexOne);

    }

}

//thread two
void *threadTwo(void *arg){
    FILE *fileTwo;
    fileTwo = fopen("hw5-2.in", "r");

    char mChr2;

    //read each char
    if(fileTwo == NULL){
        perror("file two error\n");
    }

    while(!feof(fileTwo)){
        fscanf(fileTwo, "%c\n", &mChr2);
        printf("char read: %c \n", mChr2);

        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexTwo);
        globalVAR2 = mChr2;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexTwo);

    }

}
//thread three
void *threadThree(void *arg){
    FILE *fileThree;
    fileThree = fopen("hw5-3.in", "r");

    char mChr3;

    //read each char
    if(fileThree == NULL){
        perror("file three error\n");
    }

    while(!feof(fileThree)){
        fscanf(fileThree, "%c\n", &mChr3);
        printf("char read: %c \n", mChr3);

        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexThree);
        globalVAR3 = mChr3;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexThree);

    }

}

//main should open an out file for writing
int main(){

    //open a file for writing
    FILE *mainWriting;
    mainWriting = fopen("hw5.out", "w");

    FILE *count;
    count = fopen("hw5-1.in", "r");
    char cc;
    int nu=0;

    while(fscanf(count, "%c\n", &cc) == 1){
        nu += 1;
    }
    rewind(count);
    fclose(count);

    //write the global value into the outfile

    //the mutexes initialized
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutexOne, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutexTwo, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutexThree, NULL);

    pthread_t pthreadOne, pthreadTwo, pthreadThree;
    pthread_create(&pthreadOne, NULL, threadOne, NULL);
    pthread_create(&pthreadTwo, NULL, threadTwo, NULL);
    pthread_create(&pthreadThree, NULL, threadThree, NULL);


    while(nu != 0){
        //write into hw5.out
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexOne);
        fputc(globalVAR1, mainWriting);
        fputc('\n', mainWriting);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexOne);

        sleep(1);
    
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexTwo);
        fputc(globalVAR2, mainWriting);
        fputc('\n', mainWriting);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexTwo);

        sleep(1);
  
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexThree);
        fputc(globalVAR3, mainWriting);
        fputc('\n', mainWriting);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexThree);

        nu -=1;
    }


    sleep(1);
    pthread_join(pthreadOne, NULL);
    pthread_join(pthreadTwo, NULL);
    pthread_join(pthreadThree, NULL);

    fclose(mainWriting);

}
```

the input files are the same number of lines and have a single character on each line.

The output of my program was expected to be:

```
a
1
@
b
2
$
c
3
%
```

(the input files are actually a bit longer. I didn't include the entire input file for simplicity. the program is supposed to handle any length of the files assuming they are all the same length)

for the input files:

hw5-1.in

```
a
b
c
```

hw5-2.in

```
1
2
3
```

hw5-3.in

```
@
$
%
```

I am only supposed to use mutexes to synchronize the three threads without flags, global counting variables, semaphores or conditionals.

my output was like this instead:

```
c
3
%
c
3
%
c
3
%
```

I have been stuck on this for some time, I might be overcomplicating it but am not sure what to do next. I would really appreciate any suggestions or hints. Thank you.

Comment: You have nothing in your code to make the extra threads pause after reading a character until the initial thread consumes that character.  It is not surprising, then, that each of the three additional threads reads through its whole input file to the end, one character at a time, before the initial thread starts outputting the results -- which by that time are the final characters of each file.

Comment: Mutexes alone are a pretty poor tool for this job.  Semaphores would be a better option, or combining condition variables with your mutexes.  Any way around, you have to ensure that each reader waits to read the second and subsequent characters until it receives some kind of positive confirmation that the writer has consumed the previous character.

Comment: @JohnBollinger is 100% right. Remember that you do not know the order of the threads execution. The consumer has to synchronize them

Answer (score 2):

Have 3 mutexes which will provide the correct readers order. All locked by the consumer thread and unlocked when it wants data from the particular thread.

Another mutex protects the global variable.

Total 6 mutexes. 3 for the correct thread order  and 3 to protect the global variables.

But using mutexes only is not the best way of achieving it.

BTW
You can have only one global variable. You do not need 3.

Comment: does that mean two different mutexes would be unlocked and locked inside the function of each thread to have the correct order?